# React Native Drawer with React Native Router Flux set up not working

Tags: android, react-native-router-flux, react-native-drawer

I am trying to set up react-native-drawer with react-native-router-flux.

I have set up the Drawer as in the flux [OTHER INFO](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/OTHER_INFO.md) doc as below

```
import React from 'react-native';
import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer';
import SideMenu from './SideMenu';
import {Actions, DefaultRenderer} from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default class NavigationDrawer extends Component {
    render(){
        const state = this.props.navigationState;
        const children = state.children;
        return (
            <Drawer
                ref="navigation"
                open={state.open}
                onOpen={()=>Actions.refresh({key:state.key, open: true})}
                onClose={()=>Actions.refresh({key:state.key, open: false})}
                type="displace"
                content={<SideMenu />}
                tapToClose={true}
                openDrawerOffset={0.2}
                panCloseMask={0.2}
                negotiatePan={true}
                tweenHandler={(ratio) => ({
                 main: { opacity:Math.max(0.54,1-ratio) }
            })}>
                <DefaultRenderer navigationState={children[0]} onNavigate={this.props.onNavigate} />
            </Drawer>
        );
    }
}
```

Then I put the drawer scenes inside Router component as below

```
render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Scene key="choice" component={ServiceChoice} title="" hideNavBar />
            // some scenes go here

            <Scene key="drawer" component={NavigationDrawer} open={false} >
                <Scene key="main" tabs={true} >
                   <Scene 
                       key="map" 
                       component={MapScreen} 
                       title="" 
                       hideNavBar 
                       initial 
                    />
                </Scene>
            </Scene>

            //some other scenes go here
        </Router>
    );
}
```

Now the problem is that from another component e.g. ServiceChoice, if I do `Actions.map()`, nothing happens.

Can anyone pls point me to what i am doing wrong? I can provide any other information needed. All imports are also correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution i finally used was to have the Drawer component surround the Routes

```
...
import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer';
...

<Drawer
          ref={(ref) => { this.props.appDrawerSet(ref); }}
          open={false}
          type="overlay"
          onOpen={() => { console.log('drawer OPENED'); }}
          onClose={() => { console.log('drawer CLOSED'); }}
          content={<SideMenu />}
          tapToClose
          openDrawerOffset={0.2}
          panCloseMask={0.2}
          negotiatePan
          styles={drawerStyles}
          tweenHandler={(ratio) => ({
            main: { opacity: Math.max(0.54, 1 - ratio) }
          })}
      >
              <Router
                  sceneStyle={styles.sceneStyle}
                  navigationBarStyle={styles.navBarStyle}
                  titleStyle={styles.titleStyle}
              >
                 <Scene key='root'>
                     //your other scennes, nested or not
                 </Scene>
              </Router>
 </Drawer>
```

I use Redux so the ref helps me to send a reference of the Drawer to an Action where I use it to update a state element/variable called appDrawer. Then I can control (open/close) the Drawer by

```
this.props.appDrawer.open()
```

or

```
this.props.appDrawer.close()
```

My application use case was better with the `tapToClose` option on the Drawer component instead of close() function though - that is usually more used in real life for closing side drawers though.